# Angular Material: custom more compact form-field without label and hint using density?

Tags: sass, angular-material2

- Angular: 15.0.4
- CDK/Material: 15.0.3
- Browser(s): Safari 16.2
- Operating System: macOS

Is it possible to custom more compact `form-field`?

.my-mat-form-field-density-5 is working.
.my-mat-form-field-density-8 `not working`.
**SassError: "mdc-density: height must be between 36px and 56px (inclusive), but received 24px."**

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@mixin my-form-field-density($density) {
    $field-typography: mat.define-typography-config(
        $body-1: mat.define-typography-level(12px, 24px, 400),
    );
    @include mat.typography-level($field-typography, 'body-1');
    @include mat.form-field-density($density);
    margin-bottom: -18px;   //  leaving a bottom margin 8px
}

.my-mat-form-field-density-5 {
    @include my-form-field-density(-5);
}

.my-mat-form-field-density-8 {
    @include my-form-field-density(-8);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A density of -8 is too dense for Angular Material. I think a max of -5 can be applied.

Comment: To better understand how density works you can have a look at [material](https://m2.material.io/design/layout/applying-density.html#components) guidelines to read more about it.

Comment: @trisek thanks.
I just want more compact.
some ui components apply density are no effect. like checkbox.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, but with a density of 1. ie everything except 0 is "too much", even 0.5 barely doesn't make the cut. wtf?

Comment: @CiriousJoker I am running into the same exact issue.

Comment: @Winnemucca I ended up overriding stuff manually