# How can I apply density for angular material table?

Tags: angular-material, material-design

Components that can apply density are listed in [this](https://m2.material.io/develop/web/supporting/density) material page and one of these components is data table.

Thank you for [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75001267/angular-material-custom-more-compact-form-field-without-label-and-hint-using-de) I found the mixin that can apply density to form field `form-field-density(-5)`. My question is where can I found all mixin or mixin for angular material table to apply density.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, it's not well documented yet, and I couldn't the find list of exported mixins either. Your best bet is looking at the source code of the `_index.scss` [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/_index.scss). It contains the list of exports together with their prefixes, e.g.

```
@forward './table/table-theme' as table-* show table-theme, table-color, table-typography,
  table-density;
```

This basically means that the mixin you're looking for is `table-density($value)`.

So something like:

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

.table-1 {
  @include mat.table-density(-1);
}
```

should work. At least in theory, since right there is a [known issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/26981) where density won't get applied if it's placed directly on the table, but it works if applied on the parent container. Working stackblitz (from the linked issue) can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kjhbfp?file=src%2Fstyles.scss).